# How to add a modeladmin extra form field to readonly_fields?

Tags: django, admin

When adding an extra form field to the `readonly_fields` of a `ModelAdmin` I get an `ImproperlyConfigured` error when opening the admin page of an instance of my model:

```
TaskClosedAdmin.readonly_fields[0], 'extra_admin_field' is not a callable or an attribute of 'TaskClosedAdmin' or found in the model 'TaskClosed'.
```

How can I add the extra field to readonly_fields?

**EDIT**

I also tried in the `get_form()` of `TaskClosedAdmin`, thinking that the fields might be updated after `super(TaskClosedAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)` :

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(TaskClosedAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    self.readonly_fields = obj._meta.get_all_field_names()
    self.readonly_fields.append('extra_admin_field')
    return form
```

and I still get the same error about `extra_admin_field` not existing... Where can I add it?

**models.py**

```
class Task(models.Model):

    # some fields


class TaskToConfirm(Task):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

**admin.py**

```
class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):

    extra_admin_field = forms.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        model = Task


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # set extra_admin_field value


class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    form = TaskForm


class TaskClosedAdmin(TaskAdmin):

     readonly_fields = ('extra_admin_field',)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is write a read-only widget and specify it directly on your form, like this:

```
from ... import ReadOnlyWidget

class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    extra_admin_field = forms.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        widgets = {
            'extra_admin_field': ReadOnlyWidget,
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # set extra_admin_field value
```

There's a readonly widget which should work (I haven't tried it) here: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1682/

Comment: Since ModelAdmin has a readonly_fields attribute, I guess something similar already exists in Django. I would just like to add my extra field to this readonly_fields.

Comment: Ok you're right, extra_admin_field is a form field, not a model field, so I cannot add it to the modeladmin readonly_fields.